# .net 8 blazor webassembly GetAuthenticationStateAsync error JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, token, blazor-webassembly

This is what is in my Program.cs:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
```

This is my custom authstateprovider:

```
    private readonly HttpClient _htttpClient;
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;

    public AuthStateProvider(
        HttpClient httpClient,
        ILocalStorageService localStorage
    )
    {
        _htttpClient = httpClient;
        _localStorage = localStorage;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var anonymousState = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));

        try
        {
            var token = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>(Account.Token);

            if (token == null)
            {
                return anonymousState;
            }

            _htttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(Utils.SplitRole(token)));
        }
        catch
        {
            return anonymousState;
        }
    }
```

It is always throwing an exception when i start the app and the login function doesn't works.

The error is: "System.InvalidOperationException : 'JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.'"

I try to put this `@rendermode InteractiveServer` and this:

```
protected override async Task **OnAfterRenderAsync**(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await GetNotification();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

private async Task GetNotification()
{
    Notification = await _localStorage.GetNotification();
}
```

in my singIn but it does not resolve the problem. And the problem when I start the app is not solve either.

.net 8 has new rules? What can I do to make this works?